# MLR: cforest learner throws error in resampling

Tags: r, random-forest, mlr

I am getting the following error when using mlr to do resampling on a conditional inference forest:

```
Error in Hmisc::rcorr.cens(-1 * y, s) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

My code is

```
surv.task <- makeSurvTask(data = bb_imp2, target = c("timeToEvent", "status"))
surv.learner <- makeLearner(cl="surv.cforest", predict.type="response", mtry=5)
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc(method="CV", iters=2)
r = resample(surv.learner, surv.task, rdesc)
r
```

For testing I have cut the data down to just 3 columns - times, status and one predictor - Glucose - and there are no NA, Inf or NaN values in the data. I can successfully train a cforest model on the data without using resampling:

```
surv.task <- makeSurvTask(data = bb_imp2, target = c("timeToEvent", "status"))
surv.learner <- makeLearner(cl="surv.cforest", predict.type="response", mtry=5)
blood_cforest <- train(surv.learner, surv.task) 
getLearnerModel(blood_cforest)

Random Forest using Conditional Inference Trees

Number of trees:  500 

Response:  Surv(timeToEvent, status, type = "right") 
Input:  Glucose 
Number of observations:  873
```

There are no character variables in the data. The structure of the data is:

```
str(bb_imp2)
'data.frame':   873 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ timeToEvent: num  373 2934 397 3005 2930 ...
 $ status     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Glucose    : num  5.2 5.6 6.7 5.5 6.1 5.9 5.8 5.7 7.7 5.5 ...
```

Why does the resampling not work? Where should I upload the data file so that others can try it out?

Comment: Is the data shareable? If yes, any file hosting service? The problem lies in the default measure of survival which is the cindex. You can avoid this by changing to another measure via the measure argument, e.g. to timetrain. Probably some predictions are NA, which causes the error. So just get the resampled predictions with measure timetrain and investigate the predictions of the single folds.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippPro. I added measures=list(timetrain) to the resample function call. Did you mean to check result$pred? In that data structure the value for response is -Inf in each row. Also in result$measures.train,the value for timetrain is NA on each iteration. What could be causing that?

Comment: That the survival method is not working for your problem at hand? That doesn't seem to be an issue of mlr, but of your algorithm/data.